# how to add unique facebook comment box to each product listing?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, facebook

Basically, I am outputting a list of product info from an SQL table like what you would see on Amazon after you search for an item. I want a facebook comment box next to each product name in the list but they have to be all unique threads such that all the facebook comment boxes contain comments that pertain only to the product they are next to. Here is the code that Facebook gives
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/198/

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just use a unique product ID to construct the unique URL for the comment box. You'll have to figure out the actual way within your shopping cart to do that, but perhaps something like http://yoursite.com/product/123456

As long as you pass in a consistent unique URL to the comment box, it will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

A default FB comment box is related to the URL it sits on. Therefore if you want a comment box for each product, you have to supply a URL for each product when you set up the comment box.